# Background process in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, job-control

I wanted to find a way to run Spock tests in headless mode.

One solution I found involves running these two commands:

```
Xvfb :99 &>/dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

This works.

I am not sure what these do precisely, although I am investigating it. But I learn that "&" at the end of a command indicates a "job control" meaning that the process is "put in the background".

Is it possible to put these two commands into a shell script and execute them that way? I have tried but it doesn't seem to result in a headless mode (you still see the JavaFX visual things flashing up during testing). I currently assume that "&" at the end of a line like this doesn't have the same effect when run in a script.

Comment: If in a script the environment variable will not escape. So any following commands, that are not in the script, will not see it.

Comment: Thanks. So if I just establish the env var as a permanent one maybe this will work... ? Just tested... seems to work.

Comment: No, `&` does not necessarily mean job control. The `&` "run-in-background" shell syntax also predates the job control. You can also run asynchronous commands in a shell script. But since there isn't any job control in scripts (_by default_, you can change that with `set -m`), you cannot bring them back to the foreground.

Comment: Your problem is that the `export DISPLAY=:99` is local to the script, and will NOT propagate to the shell you called that script from. Either source that script with `. /path/to/script`, or start your JavaFX thing from within it. And don't redirect the stderr from `Xvfb` to `/dev/null`: you won't be able to know if it failed, crashed, etc.

Comment: Thanks... just changed the title accordingly. I'm not quite clear whether setting `DISPLAY` permanently to ":99" is such a good idea. Out of my depth (obviously).

Comment: It doesn't set it permanently - it remains in the current context until you close the shell that defined it

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking of adding it to .bashrc... so this would then be a 1-line command. But it appears that the env var DISPLAY plays a critical role with display...

Comment: Instead of setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable globally, you can run specific commands as `DISPLAY=:99 xterm ...` or `env DISPLAY=:99 xterm ...` -- or `xterm -display :99 ...` or `firefox --display=:99 ...`, for applications which support the `--display` or `-display` command line switch.